# Metatrader WebRequest: get current Time of specific city

Tags: mql5

I'm using Metatrader 5 and I would like to know if is it possible to perform Webrequest to get the current and date-specific time of locations like London and NY.

I want to get the SERVER DATE (valid for backtest too) and check the London and NY time.

If so, which will be the command to put in MQL5?

I appreciate any help.

Comment: All the necessary information can be found using [Date and Time](https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/dateandtime) functions. If you run into problems creating your code, post it and you will receive much more help if you've already tried (stackoverflow is not a free code writing service)

Comment: Tks @PaulB, but the DATE/TIME functions do not perceive the DST time effectively. I'm wordering the robot in a Russian VPS (that have DST too crazy), operating accordingly in NY and London times.

Comment: If your computer has the correct timezone set then you can use the Date and Time functions to work out the timezones anywhere else